# Azure SQL DW Materialized Views

Tags: sql, view, azure-sql-database, materialize

I am trying to understand but its not obvious to me in the documentation of Azure SQL DW, if you materialize a view and any of the base tables of the view is being updated with data or data is deleted / truncated, will this affect what is accessible in the materialized view or will what was created in the materialized view at execution persist?

Comment: A Materialized View persists the data returned from the view definition query and automatically gets updated as data changes in the underlying tables. I tried All the operation you mentioned in Question on the base table of materialized view It is updating the view according to the changes perform on base table materialized view without restrictions.

Comment: thank you, so in other words any changes in the underlying table will be affected in the materialized view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A Materialized View persists the data returned from the view definition query and automatically gets updated as data changes in the underlying tables.**

I tried All the operation you mentioned in Question on the base table of materialized view It is updating the view according to the changes perform on base table materialized view without restrictions.

- **Sample data**
  [image]
- **Created Materialized view on table**
  [image]
- **Updated data in base table and performed select operation on view**
  [image]
- **Deleted data from base table and performed select operation on view**
  [image]
- **Inserted data in base table and performed select operation on view**
  [image]

After every update on base table Materialized view is getting updated automatically.

Comment: thanks appreciate the feedback!